# How to convert a GIf to video format with tranparent background?

Tags: javascript, node.js, animation, video, html5-video

I want to convert a Gif (like https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dpmw.gif) into a Video format **with transparent background**  and then want to use that in HTML video tag in a webpage . Current I am **able to convert Gif into MP4 or other format** but the **issue is that all videos contain background color.**

Is their any way to convert Gif into Video format with transparent background .

**Note : Video format should be one of MP4, WebM, and OGG .**

Comment: The only format you listed with transparency is webM. It won't work on iOS/Mac. You might be better off converting animated GIF image into **animated webP**. Just try: `convert gif to animated webp "alpha"` in Google search.

Comment: @VC.One, webp and gif both can't be control by js like pause in html5 video tag.